# Implement function and return new list js

Tags: javascript

I've only been studying javascript for three weeks now and need help on a task.

I want to implement a function, called test, which takes a list and a function as arguments. The test function should call the function that was submitted as an argument once for each value in the list, with the list value in question as an argument, and will return a NEW list containing only the list values ​​for which the argument function returned true. And I want to do that WITHOUT using the filter() method.

How can I think here? Is my code below a good start? I appreciate all the help I can get here so I can understand this.

```
let x = ["1", "2", "3"];

function test(x, s) {
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

  }
  return 
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want to use `filter` ?

Comment: Show us the output you expect

Comment: what about 'map'? or 'forEach'? or the goal is to do it without any array function?

Comment: Wait, so this is an assignment or some kind of test you are having us solve in your place ?

Comment: Yeah he's goal is to do it without it.

Comment: Yes this is one of 100 assignments/task and I ask you because i want to learn this and wondering how I can think, because I don't now. It up to you if you want to help me or not.

Comment: I'd use this as an opportunity to learn how to use the JS debugger.  Start with the simple code you have and work from there.  You are on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is a good start, it provides a way of looping through all the elements in the list, which is a good starting point. I do suggest however that you change the names of your arguments so that they better represent the data they hold.

Your next step is to call the function passed in as an argument (`f`) for each element in your list and check whether or not it `return`s true. If it does, then you can add this element to a new list (which holds the list of values to return).

Once your loop is complete, you can return this new list. Take a look at an example below to get an understand of how you might implement this:

```js
let x = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function test(lst, f) {
  let new_list = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
    if(f(lst[i])) { // check if the function gives back a "truthy" value
      new_list.push(lst[i]);
    }
  }
  return new_list;
}

let result = test(x, function(list_element) {
  return list_element % 2 === 0;  // return true if element is even
});

console.log(result);
```

You could also achieve this in a number of different ways, such as using `.reduce()` and a ternary to make the method nice and concise:

```js
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const test = (lst, f) => 
  lst.reduce((acc, elem) => f(elem) ? [...acc, elem] : acc, []);

const res = test(x, n => n % 2 === 0);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty array at the start of your function, that you populate while reading your array before returning it.

As you don't want to use `filter`, I will provide a solution using `forEach`, and an other using a basic `for` loop.

```js
let x = ["1", "2", "3"];

function testFor(list, testFct) {
  const resultArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (testFct(list[i])) {
      resultArray.push(list[i]);
    }
  }
  return resultArray;
}

function testForeach(list, testFct) {
  const resultArray = [];
  list.forEach((element) => {
    if (testFct(element)) {
      resultArray.push(element);
    }
  })
  return resultArray;
}

console.log(testFor(x, (el) => el % 2));

console.log(testForeach(x, (el) => el % 2));
```

But at the end of the day, I don't see why you could not use `filter`, as it returns a new array anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that in a simple way is this -->

```
let x = ["1", "2", "3"];

function myFunction(element){
  if (element == "1" || element == "2"){
    return true 
  }
  return false
}

function test(list, myFunction) {
  let newList = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    let element = list[i];
    if (myFunction(element)){
      newList.push(element);
    }
  }
  return newList
}

test(x, myFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another simpler way using `filter` -->

```
let x = ["1", "2", "3"];

function myFunction(element){
  if (element == "1" || element == "2"){
    return true 
  }
  return false
}

function test(list, myFunction) {
  return list.filter(myFunction)
}

test(x, myFunction)
```

Comment: Better you merge both the answers.